# Spring RequestParam with angular number format Cors error

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript

So i am trying to make a post request to this endpoint with 2 paramerers as numbers...i get the parameters  corectly.. when is posted i get
*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/user/addCartItem' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.* **error** ...
When i apply the same method from postman everythink works smooth and corectly.

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addCartItem/{cartId}{productId}", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public List<CartItem> addCartItem(@RequestParam Long cartId ,
                                      @RequestParam Long productId) {
        return cartService.addCartItem(cartId ,productId);
    }
```

```
  addCartItem(cartId:number,productId:number):Observable<any>{
    const httpParams = new HttpParams({
      fromObject:{
        cartId,
       productId,
      }
    })
    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:8080/api/user/addCartItem',{ httpParams })
  }
```

**This is the Security Config Class**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
  prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecutiryConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    @Autowired 
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;
    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    @Bean 
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/user/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/public/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                 registry.addMapping("/**") 
                 .allowedMethods("GET","POST","PUT","DELETE")
                 .allowedHeaders("*")
                 .allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How have you setup CORS in the server?

Comment: I just added the security config class from the server...but the thing is that every request works perfectly ...and i have around 15 endpoints everythink works...

Comment: Can you check your browser's network tab in developer tools and see whether you are getting this error from OPTIONS request?

Comment: I added a screenshot from the browser .

Comment: You’re adding HttpParams as body payload. I don’t think you need HttpParams at all here: return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:8080/api/user/addCartItem',{ cartId, ProductId })
  }

Comment: Add OPTIONS into the `allowedMethods` and try again once please.

Comment: but still if a iwant to make a post request with 2 parameters what should i use??also parameters type of numbers...Added OPTIONS same error

Comment: You have to remove "/{cartId}{productId}" from value like this  value = "/addCartItem".

Comment: in Angular you have to set the params like query params, you can test it by concatenating the params in the url like this `http://localhost:8080/api/user/addCartItem?cartId?=${cartId}&producId=${producID}`